# $injector:modulerr error in angularjs for the same code

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am sure that I am doing a silly mistake somewhere but I am unable to detect it. I have exactly same two js fiddles, one is working and another one doesn't, giving `$injector:modulerr` error.

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dmajumder/tG46g/13/

Non-working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dmajumder/6tyb41gu/1/

It might be a jsFiddle problem also. Forgive me if I am doing a very silly mistake but please help me to get out of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In working fiddle you included the AngularJS library `AngularJS 1.2.1`.

[image]

But in not working fiddle you forgot to add the AngularJS library.

[image]

**no wrap - in `<head>`:**

This will place your JavaScript code in the `<head>` section.

**no wrap - in `<body>`:**

This will place your JavaScript code in the `<body>` section.

I would like to note that more information can be found in [JsFiddle Documentation.](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html)

So, please add and see the magic. It will work.

Comment: Thanks Man, you saved my time :) . Another query is what is this option **LOAD TYPE:** `No wrap - in <body>`, I had to change that also.

Comment: Yes, you have to do that also. If this answer is useful for you please mark it as correct.

Comment: Sure, I will mark it correct. I wanted to know the need of that option (LOAD TYPE), what it actually does!

Comment: I updated my answer with your query. I hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

In the `not-working` jsfiddle you have not included angular.js framework

[image: Snapshot]

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. But if I don't include it here and put it inside html section under script tag like I did it here, then why doesn't it work?